# Can we call instance method of parent class from class method of child class in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
In Python 2
class P(object):
  def M1(self): print 'inside P class M1())'
class Q(P):
  def M1(self): print 'inside Q class M1()'
  @classmethod
  def M2(cls):
    super(Q,cls).M1(cls)
s = Q()
s.M2()
----------------In Python3-------
class P(object):
   def M1(self): print ('inside M1 Method of P class')
class Q(P):
  @classmethod
  def M2(cls):
    super().M1(cls) or super(Q,cls)M1(cls)
s = Q()
s.M2()
```

In Python2:
super(Q,cls).M1(cls)#Getting error from here,But we can use same statement in python 3 and it works . I just wondering whether python 2.7 can have any similar way to call parent class implementation by using super() or not .

`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this does not run in Python 3.

Comment: Please add the error (full traceback) as well to your question.

Comment: If you want your code to be Python 3 compatible (as you suggest in your question), at least use print functions instead of print statements in your example.

Comment: class P(object):

  def M1(self): print ('inside M1 Method of P class')
class Q(P):
  @classmethod
  def M2(cls):
    super().M1(cls)
s = Q()
s.M2()

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the print statements to functions, this seems to run happily inside of Python 3.7

```
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: class P(object):
   ...:     def M1(self): print('inside P')
   ...: class Q(P):
   ...:     def M1(self): print('inside Q')
   ...:     @classmethod
   ...:     def M2(cls):
   ...:         super(Q, cls).M1(cls)
   ...:

In [2]: s = Q()

In [3]: s.M2()
inside P
```

But fails in Python2 with the error

> TypeError: unbound method M1() must be called with Q instance as first argument (got type instance instead)

Exactly as the error says, because `M1` is an instance method its argument must be an instance, *not* a class. You can get around this by making `M1` static and take no arguments.

<s>I suspect this works in Python3 because of tricks inside the implementation of `super()` to support usage inside of methods. Reading through the [standard library docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) and [this](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) recommended post were helpful.</s>

This works in Python3 because it doesn't assert the type of the first argument -- it assumes the value is suitable and doesn't hit an error. An example of duck typing.

### Edit, more general to Python 3 behavior

The error OP is seeing is not actually due to `super()` but due to how Python 3 handles instance methods differently than Python 2. An example class could be

```
>>> class Foo(object):
>>>     def __init__(self):
>>>         self._bar = 0
>>>     def bar(self): 
>>>         print('baz')
>>>     def boo(self):
>>>         self._bar+=1
>>>         print(self._bar)
>>> f = Foo()
>>> Foo.bar(Foo)  # fine in Python3, TypeError in Python2
>>> Foo.bar(None)  # fine in Python3, TypeError in Python2
>>> f.bar()  # fine in both
baz
>>> Foo.boo(Foo)  # AttributeError in Python3, TypeError in Python2
```

In both cases for, Python2 has an embedded assertion that the first argument of an instance method *must* be an instance type of the matching class. Python3 does not have this assertion for -- it's happy receiving `None` or a `type` type, at least until whatever argument it received fails to work. This is a great example of [ducktyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

So `Foo.bar` works in Python3 because it doesn't actually care what the value of the argument is -- it doesn't use it. In `Foo.boo`, however, it fails with an `AttributeError` when trying to increment the `Foo._bar` instance property (because that instance property doesn't exist in the argument it was given).

Comment: So cant we call instance method from class method in python 2.7 ? But in python3 it works fine.

Comment: In Python 2.7 the `self` argument of an instance method _must_ be an instance or you'll get a `TypeError`. If you look at the type of `P.M1` in Python2 it is `unbound method P.M1`, but in Python3 it is a namespace-scoped function. So in Python3 it looks like it infers that `P.M1` is _actually_ static.

Comment: My above comment was a bit off in that Python3 isn't actually inferring anything. I updated my answer with extra information about Python3's behavior.